# ¿Cómo crear un nuevo router en express js?

Tags: nodejs

Actualmente trabajo solamente con el server app.js el cual tiene todos los ruteos, y necesito crear un nuevo router para que sea más fácil de mantener mi software, el router nuevo es `evaluacion.js`

En mi servidor principal `app.js` tengo:

```
var routesEvaluacion = require('./routes/evaluacion');
app.use('/evaluacion', routesEvaluacion);
```

y en el archivo `./routes/evaluacion.js` tengo:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();  
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/evaluacion', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('/evaluacion/crearEvaluacion', { title: 'hola' });
});



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que en tu script de inicio tienes algo como

```
var express = require('express'),

var routesEvaluacion = require('./routes/evaluacion');

var app = express();

app.use('/evaluacion', routesEvaluacion); // <-- punto de montaje
```

El archivo `./routes/evaluacion.js` debiera ser:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('/evaluacion/crearEvaluacion', { title: 'hola' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

En otras palabras, si montas las rutas de  `evaluacion.js` en `evaluacion`, entonces usar de nuevo la ruta `evaluacion` implica que debieses navegar hasta `evaluacion/evaluacion` para entrar en esa ruta.

También se podría hacer a la manera inversa. Montar esas rutas en `/` y declararlas en `/evaluacion`

En app.js

```
 app.use('/', routesEvaluacion); // <-- punto de montaje
```

En evaluacion.js

```
 router.get('/evaluacion', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('/evaluacion/crearEvaluacion', { title: 'hola' });
 });
```

(nótese que en los ejemplos omití los bodyparser y cookieparser y cualquier middleware. Tienes que adaptar lo que te puse a tu necesidad específica. Sin embargo, es importante mencionar que no necesitas redeclarar el app en tus archivos de rutas.)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera.

`./routes/evaluacion.js`

```
//De esta forma no importas ningun modulo.
exports.evaluacion = function(req, res) {
    res.render('/evaluacion/crearEvaluacion', { title: 'hola' });
};
```

`app.js`

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var funciones = require('./routes/evaluacion');
var evaluaciones = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    

app.use(bodyParser());
app.set('view engine','jade');

evaluaciones.route('/').get(funciones.evaluacion);
app.use('/evaluacion', evaluaciones);
```

Comment: no funciona, alguna otra idea?

Comment: Lo probé y funciona bien. recuerda poner bien las rutas de tus archivos.